# Using "get over with it" Vs "get it over with"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs, grammaticality-in-context, conversation

Dialog :

X:Don't you want to settle this issue?

Y: Definitelt, (1) or (2)

1.I just want to get it over with.

2.I just want to get over with it.

Should I go with (1) or (2) and why??because I'm always confused about where to put the object after phrasal verbs.

Answer (score 1):

*Get it over with* is a set phrase meaning 'finish dealing with something unpleasant so that you can forget about it'. It doesn't necessarily follow any rules.

Comment: Thank you.So can I just normally use " get over with it " without any restrictions.

Comment: No, _get over with it_ is not idiomatic. If there is a task you want to finish quickly, you want to _get it over with_.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting Thank you a lot. one last thing ,is there is any case where I use "get over with " before the object.

Comment: I can't think of one.